# Error in RadGrid : 'RowSelected' is undefined" or “'null' is null or not an object”

Tags: telerik

I am using  “ Telerik.Web.UI.dll  2009.2.826.20” in my  desktopmodule of DNN site.  This desktop module has RadGrid  which allows user to filter Records based on criteria (Username, FirstName & LastName ) specified and user can select required record from grid display.
I am getting error  "'RowSelected' is undefined"   or   “'null' is null or not an object”    while filtering the records based on criteria.  These errors occur occasionally, not always.   It is working perfectly some times with out above said errors.

I have following client side javascript for this radgrid control

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server"> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var selected_member = ""; 
var oWnd = GetRadWindow(); 

function GetRadWindow() 
{
    var oWindow = null; 
    if (window.radWindow) oWindow = window.radWindow; //Will work in Moz in all cases, including clasic dialog 
    else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;//IE (and Moz az well) 

    return oWindow; 
}

function CloseAndReload() 
{
    oWnd.BrowserWindow.document.forms[0].selected_member.value = selected_member;
    oWnd.BrowserWindow.document.forms[0].submit();
    oWnd.Close();
}


function MemberSelected(rowIndex){ 

}

function RowSelected(sender, args) 
{
    selected_member = args.getDataKeyValue("Username"); 
    CloseAndReload();
}

</script> 
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's strange, Shaji. First step is to debug your javascript to see where the issue is nested and when exactly happens. Also you may move to the latest release of the Telerik AJAX controls (my RSS told me that they have just published Q2 2010) to see if this helps.

Dick